# Animating resizing and moving UIView at the same time

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uiview, core-animation

I'd like to "Stretch" a UIView to the right side, meaning increase it's frame.size.width by foo pixels and at the same time decreasing it's frame.origin.x by foo pixels, using [UIView beginAnimations] syntax.
However, if I do that, when the animation begins the view immediately resizes, and then starts the animation for the origin.

```
CGRect currFrame = someView.frame;
currFrame.size.width += 100;
currFrame.origin.x -= 100;

[UIView beginAnimations:@"Anim1" context:nil];
someView.frame = currFrame;
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.7];
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

I've also tried breaking the animation down to 2 parts but then I can't keep the right position in place.

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Have you found any solutions yet? I am struck with the same problem, it is strange though, why the view immediately resizes and then start the animation?

Answer (score 4):

You might need to drop down to Core Animation and break this into two explicit animations:

```
CABasicAnimation *stetchAnimation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.scale.x"];
stetchAnimation.toValue = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:(someView.frame.size.width+100)/someView.frame.size.width];

CABasicAnimation *slideAnimation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.translation.x"];
slideAnimation.toValue = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:-100];

CAAnimationGroup *animationGroup = [CAAnimationGroup animation];
animationGroup.animations = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:stetchAnimation,slideAnimation,nil];
animationGroup.removedOnCompletion = NO;
animationGroup.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards;
animationGroup.duration = 0.7;

[someView.layer addAnimation:animationGroup forKey:@"animations"];
```

Comment: Thanks, but that stretches the view. What I need is to change the frame, so it can relayout it's subviews accordingly. Basically, it's something like the search field behavior in Mobile Safari (when you tap on it, it expands to the left).